# GetSolr Processor: Output json

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm using the GetSolr Processor in Nifi and want to output json.  I think I need to put a json writing schema there, but I have no Idea what this schema should look like.
I think the GetSolr does not use the wt=json (for some  reason I can't fathom), and thus I'm kinda lost... anybody ever did that?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Trial and Error found out:  If you query solr with wt=json, you'll get a list of documents embedded in a specific umbrella json.  ONLY the single document is used for the schema.

So, if you need the schema, use one of the many online avro schema generators, paste the json of a single json document in there, and use that.  Not the whole responseheader, response, doc-array, just the single doc.

To make it clearer, here an example:

```
{
        "id":132213,
        "_version_":1689861196105121792,
        "test":"asdf"
}
```

results into avro schema

```
{
  "name": "MyClass",
  "type": "record",
  "namespace": "com.acme.avro",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "id",
      "type": "int"
    },
    {
      "name": "_version_",
      "type": "long"
    },
    {
      "name": "test",
      "type": "string"
     }
 ]
}
```